# How can I enable the Hibernate option on Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

My new desktop computer came with Windows 7 (64 bit) Home Premium installed.

There is no hibernate option. It has:

- Restart
- Standby
- Switch User
- Lock
- Sleep.

Using the power options, I tried changing the sleep button to hibernate function, but no luck.
I have the same OS on a different desktop, but 32 bit, and it has the hibernate function.

The computer is only 4 days old, so I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for CMD in the Start Menu search box, then right click it and run as Administrator.  Then type this in:

```
powercfg /hibernate on
```

That should turn it on.

If you have Hybrid Sleep turned on in Power Options, it actually hibernates anyway, but also keeps the RAM powered, so that you can quickly resume.  But this does waste power if you are keeping it like that for a long time, and it't not suitable for laptops, as it uses more power than any other power option.

Comment: No luck, that didn't work.  Also, I don't have a Hybrid Sleep option in the Power Options.

Comment: @user57058: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: yes.  In another answer I read that you can't hibernate in XP,Windows Server or Vista if you have more than 4GB ram.  It doesn't mention Win7 and I have exactly 4gb ram, no more.